# Using typeorm join table with type simple array

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have two tables in my database: User and School. Here are the entity definitions for these tables:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'simple-array' })
  schoolIds: number[];
}

@Entity()
export class School {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  address: string;
}
```

I would like to perform a join between the User and School tables using createQueryBuilder in TypeORM. The User entity has a field called schoolIds which is stored as a simple array of numbers in PostgreSQL.

I try to seperate into 2 queries then map, it run success. But I wonder is it possible to use only one query to achieve this join and retrieve the associated schools for each user?

Thank you for your help!